# Java error Syntax error on token "(", ; expected ub Java function

Tags: java, function, syntax

Hi I am getting this error on my Java code

*Syntax error on token "(", ; expected*

I am trying to make a function, maybe my syntax is not correct. 
this is my code:(I point where the error is)

```
import java.io.BufferedReader; 
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
              String ruta = "C:\\Users\\HernanEi\\Desktop\\contadoresInternet.txt";


          File archivo = new File(ruta);

          String linea = null;

          try {
           FileReader lector = new FileReader(archivo);

           BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(lector);

           while( ( linea = buff.readLine() ) != null ) {
            System.out.println(linea);    
           }
           buff.close();
           lector.close();
          } catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
          } catch(IOException ex) {
          }

          final int countWord(String codigo, File archivo)<-------Error Here
          {
                 int count = 0;
                 Scanner scanner = new Scanner("C:\\Users\\HernanEi\\Desktop\\contadoresInternet.txt");
                 while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                     String nextToken = scanner.next();
                     if (nextToken.equalsIgnoreCase(codigo))
                     count++;
                 }
                 return count;
                 }
        } 
        }
```

Sorry if it is something really simple, this is all in my main class.

Comment: You need to close the main method before trying to define another one. I.e. you're missing a } before the line with the error.

Answer (score 1):

Move the `}` from the bottom of your code to the end of the main method.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader; 
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String ruta = "C:\\Users\\HernanEi\\Desktop\\contadoresInternet.txt";
    File archivo = new File(ruta);
    String linea = null;
    try {
       FileReader lector = new FileReader(archivo);
       BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(lector);
       while( ( linea = buff.readLine() ) != null ) {
         System.out.println(linea);    
       }
       buff.close();
       lector.close();
    } catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
    } catch(IOException ex) {
    }
 }

 final int countWord(String codigo, File archivo){
   int count = 0;
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner("C:\\Users\\HernanEi\\Desktop\\contadoresInternet.txt");
   while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
     String nextToken = scanner.next();
     if (nextToken.equalsIgnoreCase(codigo))
       count++;
      }
    return count;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing brace on your main method, just before the line that's giving you the error message. Unfortunately, sometimes syntax errors that are not obvious at the point they occur end up making something later appear wrong, and so the compiler's error message can be misleading.

What can help is using a good editor that understands the language. You might already be doing that. If so, the fact that your editor placed the first line of your `countWord` definition at the same level as your `main` method body is a hint that you didn't properly close out the latter.

Answer (score 0):

I re-formated your code, so the error gets more obvious

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        String ruta = "C:\\Users\\HernanEi\\Desktop\\contadoresInternet.txt";

        File archivo = new File(ruta);

        String linea = null;

        try {
            FileReader lector = new FileReader(archivo);

            BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(lector);

            while ((linea = buff.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(linea);
            }
            buff.close();
            lector.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
    } // Moved this parenthesis up

    final int countWord(String codigo, File archivo) { // <-------Error Here
        int count = 0;

        Scanner scanner
            = new Scanner("C:\\Users\\HernanEi\\Desktop\\contadoresInternet.txt");

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String nextToken = scanner.next();
            if (nextToken.equalsIgnoreCase(codigo)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return (count);
    }
}
```

Some remarks on your code:

- you should take a look at [the try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).
- you should definitely write your code with english variable-/attribute names
- even if you can neglect some parenthesis (i.e. `if`s with only a single line of code), you should write  them for clarity

Comment: Thank you very much Turing85, I see it now, I'll make sure to follow your advice.